# Swift: removefromSuperview removes constraints

Tags: ios, swift, animation, constraints, xcode-storyboard

Currently working on some swift program and I've a call to action where I remove a blurview from the superview and at the same time I'm animating 2 buttons.

Everything works like it should but there is one small problem. When I remove the blurview from my superview the constraints on my 2 buttons are being set to 0 on the bottom and animating from that position.

I don't want them to shift to 0. If I don't remove the blurview my animation is working perfectly. I've checked if my button constraints are related to the blurview, but that isn't the case. Because I assumed that it could only reset my constraints when they are relative to the blurview.

My storyboard looks the following:

```
view
  |->  camera_view
  |->  blur_view
  |->  record_label
  |->  record_button
```

The code that I'm executing is the following:

```
@IBAction func recordButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.blurView?.removeFromSuperview()
    UIButton.animateWithDuration(0.3, delay: 0.2, options: .CurveEaseOut, animations: {
        var recordButtonFrame = self.recordButton.frame
        var recordLabelFrame = self.recordLabel.frame

        recordButtonFrame.origin.y -= recordButtonFrame.size.height
        recordLabelFrame.origin.y -= recordLabelFrame.size.height

        self.recordButton.frame = recordButtonFrame
        self.recordLabel.frame = recordLabelFrame
        }, completion: { finished in
            print("Button moved")
    })
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Kind regards,

Wouter

Comment: self.blurView?.hidden = true

Comment: Thanks that solves my problem. Forgot about that. It still remains in the memory this way right? It's faster this way if I need the instance of blurview again, but slower if I don't need it?

Comment: Yes, if you just hide it it will remain in memory. Maybe you can hide it first and then remove it after the animation finishes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're animating frames while using constraints. You should be animating constrain changes / constraint constant value changes.

When you don't remove the view the layout isn't recalculated so your frame animation 'works'. It isn't correct and will get reorganised at some point in the future.

When you remove the view the layout is recalculated and everything moves around before your animation starts.

You don't give details of your constraints but it seems likely that you should be animating constraints before removing the view, then removing and ensuring the constraints are all sane on completion.

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate all the information around the constraints. Dalija Prasnikar already solved the problem by hiding it, but I think this gives a really good addition to it.

Comment: While hiding it may solve your immediate issue, if you're still animating frames your approach is still wrong and will likely cause you problems in the future

Comment: Hmm okay. Will look into constraint animation and see if I can rewrite my code. Thanks for your advice!

Comment: managed to get some constraint animation. This stuff is magic. Even way easier than frame animation. And super smooth. Going to mark your answer as the correct one. 

    ```IBAction func recordButton(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.recordLabel.text = "START"
        self.recordBottomConstraint.constant = 130
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, delay: 0.2, options: .CurveEaseOut, animations: {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            }, completion: { finished in
                print("Button moved")
        })
    }```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of removing `blurView` from `superview` you could hide it.

Replace

```
self.blurView?.removeFromSuperview()
```

with

```
self.blurView?.hidden = true
```

Comment: (Not what you ask for but) Inside the animation block self.blurView?.effect = nil will also give you an animated de-blurring effect.

Comment: Learning so much here, with one topic. Thanks Antonis for this addition. Didn't really need it, but it's useful for feature reference! @Dalija Prasnikar, thanks for solving the problem.